# rewrite htaccess for clean url and custom 404 page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do four things with .htaccess

First thing is removing the php extension from all files

so

```
www.mywebsite.com/home is written www.mywebsite.com/home.php
```

I want to change to error page so if a request is made to www.mywebsite.com/adakadabra and there is such page like  adakabra.php a custom 404.php is used unstead.

Thirdly I would like to have vain url such that users can have profile links like

```
www.mywebsite.com/Joe
```

I have a profile.php and I use a get request to get the username so the rewrite would be from
      www.mywebsite.com/joe to www.mywebsite.com/profile.php?username=joe

Last but not least

I would want to have a pages like www.mywebsite.com/p/123453

to rewrite to 
      www.mywebsite.com/p.php?photo=123453

I have the page p.php on my webserver.

Answer (score 0):

This can to it, with 3 sets of rules in /.htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]+)$ /p.php?photo=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(Joe|Mao|Napoleon|Gandi)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Here how it works:

1. www.mywebsite.com/p/123453 => /p.php?photo=123453
2. www.mywebsite.com/Joe => /profile.php?username=Joe
3. www.mywebsite.com/home => /home.php,
   www.mywebsite.com/houra/foo/bar/home => /houra/foo/bar/home.php